# Can't Update Stock Quantity on Single Product in Magento Admin

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I've just set up a Magento store and can't seem to update the stock quantity for individual products. You can see here that it doesn't give me the normal stock quantity field for me to fill out. I've gone into the global inventory settings (System -> Configuration -> Inventory) but those settings don't seem to change it either. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Probably belongs on http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have to change the product to a 'simple' product rather than a 'configurable' product in order to have that capability.

Answer (score 0):

We can see one check box checked "use con-fig settings" under manage stock, it means we are not managing stock of individual product. it will be worked according to configuration which is setup.

If we want to use of individual product just un-check the box then you will get option to manage stock.